# help with python urllib2 import error

Tags: python, import, urllib2

In my script, I've imported urrlib2 and the script was working fine. After reboot, I get the following error:

```
  File "demo.py", line 2, in <module>
    import urllib2
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/urllib2.py", line 92, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 78, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/tempfile.py", line 34, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
ImportError: cannot import name Random
```

And when I do `import random` separately, it works fine. Any ideas what might be wrong?

I'm using ubuntu 9.10 (up to date). thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual answer is that you've got a file called `random.py` in the current directory when the script is running. `tempfile` would be accidentally importing that `random` and not the stdlib `random` module.

Answer (score 0):

Check that `random` is the stdlib's module and not some arbitrary module with the same name from `sys.path`.

```
>>> inspect.getabsfile(random)
```